# Sort in subtitle for TableViewCell

Tags: ios, sorting, uitableview

I am having trouble using the `sortDescriptors` to sort out the `UITableViewCell`.  I don't get any errors but it is not working.  I know that I am missing on how to add the sort to the cell.

Any help is appreciated.  thanks

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {     

// Configure the cell...

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    let divenumberSort = NSSortDescriptor(key:"divenumber", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [divenumberSort]


    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID as String)! as! UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath{

        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as! NSManagedObject
        var divelocation = data.valueForKeyPath("divelocation") as! String
        var divenumber = data.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") as! String
        cell.textLabel!.text = "#\(divenumber)" + "  @ \(divelocation)"

        var ddate = data.valueForKeyPath("divedate") as! String
        var dnumber = data.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") as! String

        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(dnumber) date: \(ddate)"
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you cannot sort the table cells.. sort the data in your datasource instead..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to sort the list before setting the dataSource?

```
 list.sort({ $0.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") > $1.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") })
```

Comment: I get an error of "Use of unresolved identifier"list"

Comment: with 'list' I've meant a generic name for the dataSource. Replace it with your array name

Comment: Sorry, wasn't thinking there.  Another error popped up "Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'"

Comment: Try to explicit the arguments type: list.sort( { (v1: NSManagedObject, v2: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in return v1.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") > v2.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") } )

Comment: Sorry, another error "Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((NSManagedObject, NSManagedObject) -> Bool)'

Comment: With Swift 1.2, Apple indicates the use of 'sorted' instead of 'sort'...try with that

Comment: var myArray: Array<NSManagedObject> = [NSManagedObject]()
    myArray.sort({ (v1: NSManagedObject, v2: NSManagedObject) -> Bool in
        
        (v1.valueForKeyPath("number") as! Int) > (v2.valueForKeyPath("number") as! Int)
        
    })   this works for me

Comment: OK, I get no errors but it is not sorted in the tableViewCell

Comment: print the array after the sorting. Then, if the array is sorted, use it as the tableview dataSource

Comment: Sorry, can't print as the simulator keeps crashing after I hit the "+" to add into coredata